# How do I defeat Gohma?

Tags: zelda-wind-waker

I have been playing through Wind Waker on GameCube, and I have been stuck at the Gohma boss fight for a week, now.

I have tried many walk-throughs, and I understand what is going on in the battle, but **I keep getting hit and killed by his arm attack.**

How do you beat Gohma in The Legend of Zelda: Wind Waker?

Comment: What, exactly, are you having an issue with when fighting Gohma?  Is there a specific strategy that's not working, or a move that's always hitting you?

Comment: His move where he hits me with his arm keeps hitting me and I just want to light my controller on fire!

Comment: at close voters: please go play windwaker.  Gohma is one of the more difficult bosses if you are walking into it for the first time yet simple if you can execute the trick.  There aren't really two questions that can be asked about this boss.

Comment: I wouldn't say Gohma is *difficult*, but the solution to defeating it is far less obvious than most zelda bosses that have a giant glowing eye are.

Comment: You say that you tried many walkthroughs, but don't explain what you've tried. Even if you somehow get hit by all the arm attacks, you should still be able to kill Gohma before she kills you. You need to include more detail of what you've tried and which part of the fight is causing problems for this to be a good question. That aside, I just Googled "wind waker gohma fight" and got 5 videos showing exactly what to do.

Answer (score 2):

This is a two phase fight.  The first phase is more difficult and it sounds like the one you are having trouble with.

In the first phase, Gohma has armor and will strike you with her arms.  The natural thing to try is to grapple Gohma's eye - but that won't work as the armor plating protects her.

You need to grapple the dragon tail which is swinging from the ceiling.  Some people go offensively, focusing on grappling the tail only.  Others go defensively, avoiding arm attacks and waiting to grapple until an arm is stuck or the boss takes a break.  **The attacks may be easier to avoid if you focus target the boss.**  If the boss places both arms on the ground, then a fire attack is coming - roll past the arms to avoid it.

Once the tail is grappled, swing across to the other side (don't fall in the lava).  It is not important to land on the upper levels.  After you land, the roof will fall on Gohma, weakening her armor.  You will be unable to repeat the grapple until Gohma replaces the roof (this takes a few seconds).  After doing this three times, the armor will break and you're on to phase two.

Phase two is much easier.  Without her armor, you are free to grapple the eye and then attack with the sword.  There is little reason to avoid attacks, just get the kill.

Comment: added in a solution video, as I felt it could improve an already good answer. Also demonstrates how easy the answer is to the close voters. Feel free to remove it if you disagree

Comment: A video of someone who isn't useless would be better.